# UIImageView scope. Accessing from another class

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiimageview

Here's part of the code I'm working with: http://pastie.org/2472364

I've figured out how to access the UIImageView from another method within the same class file in which it was programmatically created.

However, I was wondering how I'd access that same UIImageView from within the LetterTiles.m file, specifically within the touchesMoved method. The way I wrote the code in the sample, it will only show if the frames intersect if they're on top of each other when the otherMethod is called. Of course, I need to be able to check if the views intersect within the actual touchesMoved method. I'm sure it's something super easy, but I'm just not sure how to do it.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, and using the code you already have, I would go down this route. This isn't what I would do personally, just FYI. The structure is a bit shakey with the way it sounds like you want this.

Create the place holder UIImageView in the touchesBegan function, then check to see if they intersect when the user stops moving the image.

```
#import "LetterTiles.h"

@implementation LetterTiles
@synthesize placeHolder;

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    // Retrieve the touch point (I consider this useful info to have, so I left it in)
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    startLocation = pt;

    // Create a place holder image wherever you want
    [self setPlaceHolder:[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(39, 104, 70, 70)] autorelease]];
    [newImage setImage[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeHolder.png"]] autorelease];


}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:[self superview]];

     [self setCenterPoint:pt];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
     LetterTiles *movingTile = self;

     if (CGRectIntersectsRect([movingTile frame], [placeHolder frame])) {
         NSLog(@"Touched");

         [self setFrame:[placeHolder frame]];
     }
}
```

Comment: Yeah you're right, I should have just explained what I was trying to do ultimately. My bad.

When I touch on a letter tile, I want it to create a UIImageView somewhere in the middle of the screen. That UIImageView will be the "place holder" for the letter tile that was touched / dragged. The user will drag the letter tile over the "place holder" and the letter tile will snap into place on top of the place holder. That way the letter tiles line up. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yea, that makes a lot more sense. I rewrote my post to fit that idea. The structure for this is a bit irregular. For one, I would move the `placeHolder` stuff into a parent view so you can control it better than making `placeHolders` in the object and removing them, etc.

Comment: You sir are epic. Thank you very much for your help and code. It's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a protocol called ViewMoved which will contain one method otherMethod.
2. implement that in myMainViewController
3. take a delegate property of type ViewMoved in LetterTiles.
4. Assign self when you make new object of type LetterTiles in myMainViewController.
5. On every movement of touch call oherMethod of delegate and check whether any views of type LetterTiles are intersecting or not.

This will catch any intersection when any of the view is moved.....

If above is not matching with your question then write here......